# openssl and keytool conflict in PEM

Tags: nginx, openssl, keytool

I have created a self-signed certificate in nginx server in ubuntu as below:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
```

Coverted crt to pem using open ssl:

```
openssl x509 -in nginx-selfsigned.crt -out nginx-selfsigned.pem -outform PEM
```

When I import this certificate using keytool in debian, the import process is successful:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -keystore /certs -storepass changeit -file nginx-selfsigned.pem -alias some alias
```

But after that, the certificate isn't trusted. Why the importing certificate isn't trusted?

Any suggestion about this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the self signed certificate to be trusted, it must be in the "Trusted CAs" certificate store on each client that is connecting. Depending on your browser, you should be able to view the cert and see why it doesn't trust it also (e.g. not yet valid, expired, name mismatch, not from trusted CA, etc.)

Comment: I have added certificate: sudo cp /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. But still I have this error from responding server: java.security.cert.CertificateException: None of the TrustManagers trust this certificate chain

Comment: Is this error when you access the web page, or what are you using this certificate for?

Comment: I'm using this certificate for a web service

Comment: Where is the error coming from? The web page or trying to install the cert?

Comment: I have imported my webservice certification into responding server with keytools.

Comment: So where is the error `java.security.cert.CertificateException: None of the TrustManagers trust this certificate chain` coming from?

Comment: this error is in responding server. There are 2 servers. Responding server send post request to my web service.

Comment: The responding server, doesn't trust my webservice certificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58481/discussion-between-cory-knutson-and-phpexe).